# LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected:LoginFilter

Tags: spring-webflux, gateway, reactor-netty

console print:

> io.netty.buffer.AdvancedLeakAwareByteBuf.readBytes(AdvancedLeakAwareByteBuf.java:496)
>     org.springframework.core.io.buffer.NettyDataBuffer.read(NettyDataBuffer.java:149)
>     org.springframework.core.io.buffer.NettyDataBuffer.read(NettyDataBuffer.java:38)
>     ipf.gwservice.filter.LoginFilter$1.lambda$writeWith$0(LoginFilter.java:61)
>     reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:107)

error line :      dataBuffer.read(content);

How I fix it

```
 ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
        DataBufferFactory bufferFactory = response.bufferFactory();
        ServerHttpResponseDecorator decoratedResponse = new ServerHttpResponseDecorator(response) {
            @Override
            public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
                if (body instanceof Flux) {
                    Flux<? extends DataBuffer> fluxBody = (Flux<? extends DataBuffer>) body;
                    return super.writeWith(fluxBody.map(dataBuffer -> {
                        byte[] content = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                        dataBuffer.read(content);
                        ReferenceCountUtil.release(dataBuffer);
                        dataBuffer = null;

                        return bufferFactory.wrap("...........".getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8));
                       }));
                }
                return super.writeWith(body);
            }
        };
        return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().response(decoratedResponse).build()); // replace response with decorator
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an underlying problem while using Response Decorator involving reading byte buffer. I had this problem and after weeks of trying with various suggestion as options, managed to pin-point this problem using a sample application - `https://github.com/nilavalagansugumaran/gateway-netty-memory-leak-issues`. Spring-Gateway team referred me to an alternate approach ie `ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilter` which looks resolved the issue. Actual issue reported to Spring-Gateway team https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/664. Hope this helps.